# Can I sell a product for profit if I received it for free?

Tags: business

I got a mobile in free from my college, (a company visited the college and gave free mobiles to all students) but I sold it to my friend on market price. So is that permissible or not in Islam?

Comment: With what intention did they give you the mobile? If there was some condition with it that you should do some specific tasks with it for the studies then may be you did wrong but if it was just as gifts and no specifics given then it was your property and should be fine. The intention counts here.

Comment: There is no condition. Just for our use and their company peermotion. They give us mobile by switching to their network and we did it.

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer is yes.

To explain why I said simple, we are assuming that the mobile was given with no conditions. In that case you are welcome to sell it for any price that the buyer is willing to pay.